# Sequential buttons and actions in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

I am programming a little GUI in which the user can upload an excel file by pressing the button "Browse File Directory". After that, the program should show the first 5 lines as a preview of the data. After that preview and only after that preview, I want the button "Get statistics" to be displayed. And by clicking on "Get statistics", the use can see some basic statistics on the data.
Here's my code:

```
import os
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 
import pandas as pd

    
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')  # On Windows System
clear()

data = pd.DataFrame()
def open_file():
    global data
    global root
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Excel Files', '*.xlsx')])
    if file is not None: 
        label1 = Label(root, text=file.name)
        label1.pack()
        #if label1 is True:
        data = pd.read_excel(file.name)
        label2 = Label(root, text='Preview', font=('Helvetica', 12)) 
        label2.pack()
        label3 = Label(root, text=data.head()) 
        label3.pack() 
    
    return data
    

def click_btn1():
    btn1 = Button(root, text ='Browse File Directory', command =lambda:open_file())
    btn1.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10)


def statistics():
    data.describe()
    
   
def click_btn2():
    btn2 = Button(root, text = 'Get statistics', command=lambda:statistics())
    btn2.pack(pady = 100)

root = Tk() 
root.geometry('700x600')

click_btn1()

click_btn2()

mainloop()
```

Here's a content example of data in the excel file:

| Date | Rainfall |
| --- | --- |
| 12/10 | 15 |
| 13/10 | 10 |

But, running my code, the two buttons appear at the same time and the preview is displayed under the second button. It should be displayed under the first one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Btw not related to the question, but instead of `askopenfile`, you can use `askopenfilename` if you just want the filename instead of a file object. Otherwise, it's best if you close the file using `file.close()`.

Comment: Note that when `open_file()` is executed, new set of labels will be created.  Is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are calling `click_btn2` (which creates the second button) right after `click_btn1` (which creates the first one).

You need to move the creation of the second button into the function that open the `excel` file:

```py
def open_file():
    global data
    global root
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Excel Files', '*.xlsx')])
    if file is not None: 
        label1 = Label(root, text=file.name)
        label1.pack()
        #if label1 is True:
        data = pd.read_excel(file.name)
        label2 = Label(root, text='Preview', font=('Helvetica', 12)) 
        label2.pack()
        label3 = Label(root, text=data.head()) 
        label3.pack() 
        click_btn2()
        file.close()

    return data

...

root = Tk() 
root.geometry('700x600')

click_btn1()
# click_btn2() removed from this section
mainloop()
```

---

In addition if you are not passing any arguments to the functions inside the lambda you can simply take off the lambda and pass a pointer to the function.

#### For example:

`command =lambda:open_file()) --> command = open_file)`

The revised version:

```python
import os
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 
import pandas as pd

    
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')  # On Windows System
clear()

data = pd.DataFrame()

def open_file():
    global data
    global root
    
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Excel Files', '*.xlsx')])
    if file is not None: 
        label1 = Label(root, text=file.name)
        label1.pack()
        #if label1 is True:
        data = pd.read_excel(file.name)
        label2 = Label(root, text='Preview', font=('Helvetica', 12)) 
        label2.pack()
        label3 = Label(root, text=data.head()) 
        label3.pack() 
        click_btn2()
        file.close()

    return data
    

def click_btn1():
    btn1 = Button(root, text='Browse File Directory', command=open_file)
    btn1.pack(side=TOP, pady=10)

def statistics():
    data.describe() # You also forgot a print here
    
def click_btn2():
    btn2 = Button(root, text='Get statistics', command=statistics)
    btn2.pack(pady=100)

root = Tk() 
root.geometry('700x600')

click_btn1()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @nokla for your answer, it works. The comments of TheLizzard and acw1668 are also useful. Thank you guys!